# Executable application run together with a website

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

i have create a website web form in asp.net
and i need an executable timer application that run alongside my website and check data in my database and make some function
do you have any idea how to make that 
or any example please

thank

Comment: I assume the server is under your control? If so its simplest to just create a console application and have the task scheduler run it according to your desired schedule.

Comment: no no i'm using visual studio for now, what i want is a an application that run alonside my website, it will check data in database and make some function accordinly, some tell to use the store procedure but will the store procedure execute the function needed

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a console application within visual studio, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1sx6ed2.aspx). Otherwise you could create a [service application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that would have it's access privileges and state managed by windows services. With the console app, the easiest would be to have it run within [windows task scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7). With a service based app, you could simply have a timer within the app that could fire every couple of minutes to perform the necessary logic/checks on your DB that you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same design with task scheduler. You can run your exe with following controller actions:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcessesByName("Scheduler");
        if (processlist.Length > 0)
        {
            ViewData["isProcessWorking"] = "true";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["isProcessWorking"] = "false";
        }
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Restart()
    {
        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcessesByName("Scheduler");
        foreach (var item in processlist)
        {
            item.CloseMainWindow();
        }

        string str = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "TaskScheduler\\Scheduler.exe").ToString();
        Process deneme = Process.Start(str);
        return new JsonResult();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Stop()
    {
        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcessesByName("Scheduler");
        foreach (var item in processlist)
        {
            item.CloseMainWindow();
        }
        return new JsonResult();
    }
```